# Fabric Distribution with Gradle not Sending Invitation

Tags: android, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I am trying to distribute Android beta builds via fabric following https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html.

After running `gradle assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease`
, the build was successfully uploaded to fabric, but the problem is that nobody was invited for testing. Any settings I am missing here? 
[image]

And this is my setting in the gradle file:

```
ext.enableCrashlytics = true
ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes="Hello World"
ext.betaDistributionEmails="yzhong@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The settings has to be under **android > buildTypes > release**, as the following:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes="Hello World"
            ext.betaDistributionEmails="yzhong@gmail.com"
```